# 'php' or 'cake', 'bake' is not recognized as an internal or external command + cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I ant to back some stuff. but unfortunately cake bake doesn't work.

I get this in console:

```
'php' or 'cake' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: Do you have `php` on your `PATH` environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on MyComputer /

properties/

Advance system settings/

Environment Variables /

system variables part/

select path

-> edit -> add this to the path

> Cakephp 2.x

- C:\wamp\www\Name_of_cake_folder\app\Console;
- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12 or php version

> Cakephp 3.x

- C:\wamp\www\Name_of_cake_folder\bin;
- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12 or php version

**Note:** Make sure there is no space between paths

Answer (score 2):

If php isn't in your path, it is of course appropriate to add it.

## Use Console/cake

However, it's not necessary to have `cake` in your include path (or IMO a good idea). In version 1.x it was the preferred/recommended way to access CakePHP's cli but not any more.

Instead of using an executable in your path, use the executable for whichever application is most relevant:

```
cd some\app
Console\Cake

Welcome to Cakephp v.....
-------------------------
```

This also avoids problems where multiple applications are installed using different versions of CakePHP.