# Unable to get Bake Console working and all answers are outdated

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake, cake-bake

I have a CakePHP project in

> C:/xampp/htdocs/cms2

I'm trying to use bake console, but when I run "bin/cake" in the command prompt it says that `'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I followed [this](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/2/en/index.html) and It got installed and I restarted my PC.

So, I 'cd' my way from the console to my project's directory and I type in `composer require --dev cakephp/bake:"^2.0"` for a second time just to make sure:

[image: Console when I run the command]

This means bake is installed, right? When I first ran this command, I had some files downloaded and installed, this picture is after running the command for a second time. I have PHP set up correctly in my Environment Variables. I've been doing my research and I still can't find my answer.

Things I've done:

1. I followed this article [here](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/cakephp-bake-console-in-windows), but it lead to nowhere. I have no cake\console folder.
   This is what my File Explorer of my project looks like, so there's no cake/console
   [image]
2. Then I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992676/how-do-i-get-the-bake-console-for-cakephp) stackoverflow thread
   However it was for WAMP, so I couldn't find anything similar. When I search for "Console" in my project folder, I find about 30 "Console" files and folders. When I do `php -v` I get: PHP 7.3.27
3. I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882489/php-or-cake-bake-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-c) thread and I add `C:\xampp\htdocs\cms2\bin` to my "Path" System Environmental Variables, but still nothing happens.

I'm out of ideas and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need to bake my models and controllers and what not and I am unable. I also took a picture of my SYSTEM Environmental Variables, just in case it could help someone help me.

[image]

Comment: One word, "_backslash_".

Comment: I don't get it, where do I look at?

Comment: `bin/cake` contains a _forward_ slash.

Comment: @Sibuscus https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607322/1127933

Comment: Oh, wow, nice, are you serious? I literally wasted a whole day yesterday trying to figure everything out, reinstalling literally every program I used. Who would've taught that the cake cookbook had it wrong? This command is literally from their cookbook:
bin/cake bake model users

Comment: @Sibuscus the bin is not the command, but the folder where the cake command is located.

Comment: There's actually a note for Windows CMD users ;) https://book.cakephp.org/bake/2/en/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was following the documentation in the cakePHP cookbook and they had it typed:

[image]

Turns out, I had to use

```
bin\cake bake model users
```